# How to integrate <mat-autocomplete> from parent component with <mat-option> from child component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to implement an auto-completable component with **dynamic data and UI**. I want to achieve it with the help of **Angular Material Autocomplete** component. For example, suppose I want the first two rows to have different data and styles from the rest of the options.

I know how to implement the business part with the help of services. But **how to help Angular Material recognize the mat-option's in child components**?

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sibghl?file=src/app/auto-completable/auto-completable.component.html)

Parent Component (nw-auto-completable-input):

```html
<tsn-input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           label="number"
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"></tsn-input>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

One of the children's components that hold mat-option's (for instance, nw-auto-completable-card):

```html
<mat-option>65165486451</mat-option>
<mat-option>65165486451</mat-option>
```

The way I call the parent component:

```html
<nw-auto-completable-input>
          <nw-auto-completable-card></nw-auto-completable-card>
          <nw-auto-completable-deposit></nw-auto-completable-deposit>
</nw-auto-completable-input>
```

Comment: give me stackblitz example to fix the issue

Comment: @Exception https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sibghl?file=src/app/auto-completable/auto-completable.component.html

Comment: @Exception Did you come up with a solution? :)

Comment: Need to look into ng-content, never used it

Comment: @Exception ng-content is not important here. Suppose I directly use auto-completable-card and auto-completable-deposit instead of ng-content. It again doesn't work.

Comment: auto-completable-card is the component that you created right...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247615/discussion-between-exception-and-ariyadey).